# retrieve data friom ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist

i have a ArrayList of Object type and that array list contain another arraylist obj.

Ex-

```
ArrayList<Object> obj=new ArrayList<Object>();
ArrayList<Object> obj2=new ArrayList<Object>();

obj2.add(101);//contain core data



obj.add(obj2);//storing obj2 into the obj
```

how can i get 101 from obj2??

Comment: Consult `ArrayList's` documentation, it's a short google search away.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would do this, but first you would get the index it's stored at, and then get the element from the ArrayList. I'd recommend using the List interface though rather than the implementation of that interface which is ArrayList.

```
obj2.get(obj2.indexOf(101))
```

To use the list interface and type inference

```
List<Object> obj=new ArrayList<>();
List<Object> obj2=new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Jonny Henley that a simple [`ArrayList` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) look-up should be enough here but, in case the poster is a newbie, here's my answer.

```
// Your code
ArrayList<Object> obj=new ArrayList<Object>();
ArrayList<Object> obj2=new ArrayList<Object>();

obj2.add(101);//contain core data
obj.add(obj2);//storing obj2 into the obj

// My code: Get 101 from obj2
// Because obj2 is in-scope here, and assuming that you know
// obj2 is not empty...

Object data = obj2.get(0);

// Above, data will be an Integer object due to auto-boxing
// If it is null, auto-unboxing will throw NullPointerException
// If data == null, set dataInt to any value to indicate that.
// Here, I am setting it to -1, assuming -1 is an invalid value
// for your application.

int dataInt = (data != null) ? data : -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

by using this approche i'm able to get data from obj;

```
Object getData=obj.get(0);
ArrayList<Object> arrayListObject=new ArrayList<Object>();
arrayListObject=(ArrayList)getData;
int a=(int)arrayListObject.get(0);
```